# how to add discount information in paypal php rest api?

Tags: php, paypal

I am currently using paypal php rest api 0.6. I am unable set discount amount.

I am able to see the item list, tax and shipment amount. But don't know how to configure discount.
                $payer = new Payer();
                $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

```
            $item = new Item();
            $item->setQuantity("1");
            $item->setName("Classic Shirt");
            $item->setPrice("100.00");
            $item->setCurrency("USD");
            $item->setSku("CS00001");
            $item2 = new Item();
            $item2->setQuantity("1");
            $item2->setName("Classic Brown Shirt");
            $item2->setPrice("100.00");
            $item2->setCurrency("USD");
            $item2->setSku("CS00002");

            $amount = new Amount();
            $amount->setCurrency("USD");

            $amountDetails = new Details();

            $amountDetails->setSubtotal('200');
            $amountDetails->setTax('10');
            $amountDetails->setShipping('10');
            //$amountDetails->setDiscount('10');
            $amount->setDetails($amountDetails);
            $amount->setTotal("210.00");
            $item_list = new ItemList();
            $item_list->setItems(array($item,$item2));

            $transaction = new Transaction();
            $transaction->setAmount($amount);
            $transaction->setDescription("This is incredibly awesome.");
            $transaction->setItem_list($item_list);

            $baseUrl = getBaseUrl();
            $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
            $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment.php?success=true")
                    ->setCancelUrl("$baseUrl/ExecutePayment.php?success=false");

            // ### Payment
            // A Payment Resource; create one using
            // the above types and intent set to 'sale'
            $payment = new Payment();
            $payment->setIntent("sale")
                    ->setPayer($payer)
                    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
                    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
```

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

In the current version of the REST API you can use negative values for a discount, for example:

```
$itemTmp = new \PayPal\Api\Item();
$itemTmp->setName('Discount')
->setCurrency('EUR')
->setQuantity(1)
->setPrice(-10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mention on discounts in the [API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/).

I suggest you simply calculate the discount yourself, and call the `->setPrice` with a discounted price.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a negative number and make the description discount

Comment: paypal only allows positive values for items, so this won't work.

Comment: Actually, PayPal REST can accept negative numbers. But cannot be -10. Has to be -10.00. I had problems with it, and it finally accepted when I made it -10.00

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal Rest API is tricky because you indeed cannot add a discount using ->setDiscount(); ALTHOUGH the jsondecode of the payment shows an array DISCOUNT=>"" in Payment>Amount->Details...